# Writing GNF grammar for a CFL

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, finite-automata, automata, automata-theory

Hello I would like to ask you this question.

I was supposed to compute (manually) a grammar in Greibach Normal Form, that generates the language

`L = {ai bj ck | i + j = 2k  and  k >= 1}`

I really have no idea. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance
Chriss

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: That should be feasible. Create a grammar first, then transform to GNF. Or explain why that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Context Free Grammar CFG for your language `La = {ai bj ck | i + j = 2k  and  k >= 1}`.

Below is answer with language `L = {ai bj ck | i + j = k  and  k >= 1}`.

**CFG:**

```
S --> aAc | bBc |
A --> aAc | B   |  ^
B --> bBc | ^
```

**What is GNF?**

One important form of CFG is Greibach Normal Form GNF:

```
   A --> aα   
   Where α ∈ V* (any number of variables including zero)
```

**Note:** nul `^` can't be a symbol on RHS of any production accept start symbol `S` with constrict that if `S --> ^` is a production in grammar then `S` can't be appear on RHS of any other production in grammar.

Any CFG can be written in GNF form.

**How to convert CFG in GNF?**

Note in CFG I written above have nul productions `A --> ^` and `B --> ^` and a Unit production `A --> B`. Unit productions and nul productions are not allowed in GNF form. Although other productions can easily written in GNF form by introduction in GNF productions in grammar e.g. `S --> aAc`  can be rewrite as `S --> aAC and C --> c`.

So below I am  rewriting equivalent CFG for language and removing nul and unit productions called simplified CFG.

**Simplified CFG:**

```
S --> aAc | bBc | ac | bc
A --> aAc | bBc 
B --> bBc | bc
```

Now this grammar can easily converted into GNF form by introducing new GNF production `C --> c` and replace `c` by `C` in other production rules.

**GFN for language L:**

```
S --> aAC | bBC | aC | bC
A --> aAC | bBC 
B --> bBC | bC
C --> c
```

<sup>By mistake I written a wrong grammar I will update answer for language `La`</sup>

**Edit**

`La = {ai bj ck | i + j = 2k  and  k >= 1}`.

**CFG for L<sub>a</sub>:**

```
S --> aaAc | bbBc | abBc
A --> aaAc | B    | abBc |  ^
B --> bbBc | ^
```

**Simplified CFG:**

```
S --> aaAc | bbBc | abBc | aac | bbc | abc 
A --> aaAc | bbBc | abBc | aac | abc
B --> bbBc | bbc
```

**GFN for language L<sub>a</sub>:**

Add three new production rules: `X --> a`, `Y --> b` and `Z --> c`.

Change programmer and replace terminal by variables:

```
S --> aXAZ | bYBZ | aYBZ | aAZ | bYZ | aYZ  
A --> aXAZ | bYBZ | aYBZ | aXZ | aYZ
B --> bYBZ | bYZ
X --> a
Y --> b
Z --> c
```

Comment: Many thanks, but actually the resulting grammar doesn't produce the language. i.e. S->bC-> bc is not contained in the given language. And there are words that belongs to the language that I can't produce, like "abc"

Comment: @user2799534 ok check updated answer, let me know if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

About Below answer CFG of `La = {ai bj ck | i + j = k  and  k >= 1}` is wrong

Your Simplified CFG:

`S --> aAc | bBc | ac | bc .
 A --> aAc | bBc .
 B --> bBc | bc  .`

Because the above language `L = {ai bj ck | i + j = k  and  k >= 1}` produce the language `aabccc` but your Simplified CFG not produce it .

Right CFG is

Simplified CFG

`S --> aAc | bBc | ac | bc
A --> aAc | bBc | bc | ac
B --> bBc | bc`

Correct it, Second language has the same problem.

Thanks!